# Leaflet - personalizing the tooltip

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip, gis, geoserver

I am trying to personalize the leaflet tooltip to display only certain features.

My code is as follows

```
var source = L.WMS.source(
  "http://13.59.209.218:8080/geoserver/ec2_3/wms?",
  options
);
var LandMaps = source.getLayer("ec2_3:PLOTSEDIT", {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
      var content =
        "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>" +
        "<tr><th>ID</th><td>" + feature.properties.id + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><th>Plot No</th><td>" + feature.properties.plotno_1 + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><th>FR Source</th><td>" + feature.properties.frsrcname + "</td></tr>" +
        "<tr><th>More Details</th><td><a href= 'MoreDetails.html' target='_blank'></a></td></tr>" +
        "<table>";
      layer.bindPopup(content);
      console.log(feature.properties);
    }
  },
});
LandMaps.addTo(map);
```

The result still remain the default tooltip without any formatting. How do I specify a custom tooltip with my code. I have provided the test Geoserver for your testing.

Regards,

James

Comment: I'm reading the docs for [L.WMS.source](https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms#lwmssource), and I see no references to `onEachFeature`. So I'm wondering what's the thought process that lead you to use `onEachFeature` on a `L.WMS.source`.

Answer (score 0):

WMS does not have onEachFeature reference.

After some searches I found out that one simply needs to use WFS on Geoserver and enable the JSONP in the WEBINF's web.xml file.

This was the code that I used

[enter link description here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64406/getting-wfs-data-from-geoserver-into-leaflet)